# SQLite: How to UPDATE column using count(*) range?

Tags: sqlite, count, range

I'm not sure I'm using right terminology here.

[image: small part of column]

Basically I want to update entire "id" column using count(*) [485] as a delimiter, in an ascending order, so the resulting row value will correspond with rownumber (not the rowid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this should work for you:

```
UPDATE tbl_name SET id=rowid
```

**EDIT**
If that's is the case -> then it's a lit bit more tricky, since SQlite doesn't support variables declaration.
So what I suggest is,

1. To create temporary table from select of your original table which makes it's rowids to be as row numbers 1,2,3 etc...
2. Set it's rowNum (the needed row number column) as each rowid
3. Then replace the original table with it.

Like this: (assume original table called orig_name)

```
            CREATE TABLE tmp_tbl AS SELECT rowNum FROM orig_name;
            UPDATE tmp_tbl SET rowNum=rowid;
            DROP TABLE orig_name;
            CREATE TABLE orig_name AS SELECT rowNum FROM tmp_tbl;
            DROP TABLE tmp_tbl;
```

Comment: No, "id" already corresponds to rowid. As I wrote I want it to change so it corresponds to rownumber.

Comment: Total number of rows can be checked with SELECT id from tbl_name or SELECT count(*) FROM tbl_name. I need to work with this value.

Comment: Check the Edit that I just added. If helped, don't forget to vote up)

Comment: Your solution is excellent. Unfortunately my 'reputation' is apparently too low to vote up for now.

Comment: No problem, I glad to help anyway. Good luck)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid

You can use some inner database variables such as rowid, oid etc to get what you need.

[edit]
Think I just understood what you meant, you want for each insert action, add a value that is the total count of rows currently in the table?
If so, try something like this:

UPDATE tbl_name
SET id = (select count(*) from tbl_name)
WHERE yada_yada_yada

Comment: I guess what I need is to use ROW_NUMBER, but I can't. See my previous comments.